# Confusion about maven-war-plugin and jetty-maven-plugin

Tags: maven-2, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to get the `run-exploded` goal of the jetty-maven-plugin to work correctly. I find the documentation somewhat lacking on what I need to do to set this up.

I *believe* I have a standard WAR-file setup. (The reason I wrote "believe" is that I find the maven-war-plugin documentation lacking as well.) When I build my webapp using `maven package`, I get the following in my target folder:

```
classes
maven-archiver
surefire-reports
test-classes
tmp
mywebapp-version
mywebapp-version.war
```

where `mywebapp-version` is the exploded war and `mywebapp-version.war` is the packaged one. So far so good (I think?).

Now, running `mvn jetty:run-exploded`, it seems the default deploy folder is `target/tmp/webapp/mywebapp-version.war/`. This folder exists, but contains no files except for a webapp-cache.xml. This seems wrong to me.

I also tried to actively set the `webApp` configuration element to `${project.build.directory}/mywebapp-version/`, but `run-exploded` seems to ignore it (despite the documentation stating otherwise).

What am I doing wrong? It looks as if I am missing something simple since no one else appears to be running into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, running `mvn jetty:run-exploded`, it seems the default deploy folder is `target/tmp/webapp/mywebapp-version.war/`. This folder exists, but contains no files except for a `webapp-cache.xml`. This seems wrong to me.

According to the documentation of the [`jetty:run-exploded`](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/maven-plugin/run-exploded-mojo.html) mojo, the default value for the `tmpDirectory` is `target/jetty-tmp`.

> I also tried to actively set the `webApp` configuration element to `${project.build.directory}/mywebapp-version/`, but run-exploded seems to ignore it (despite the documentation stating otherwise).

The `webApp` defaults to `${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}` so I'm not sure your "active" configuration changed anything.

> What am I doing wrong? It looks as if I am missing something simple since no one else appears to be running into the same problem.

Well, what is the problem actually? :) What are you expecting exactly (I'm suspecting a misunderstanding of what is supposed to happen).

By the way, I find the [Maven Jetty Plugin Configuration Guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) and the documentation of Jetty's mojos pretty decent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Part of the confusion is that I'm using the new version of the plugin (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_Maven_Plugin) that seems to have slightly changed behavior from previous versions.

I am expecting that run-exploded should build the war and then the exploded war should be deployed on Jetty. When I get back to the code I will try to use an older version of the plugin instead and see if that works.

Comment: @waxwing: Actually, I'm not sure the behavior of `jetty:run-exploded` has changed (I didn't spot any obvious difference between the "old" configuration guide and the "new" one). But don't hesitate to post some feedback later.